# Expand spatial exent of a raster using another raster

Tags: r, raster, terra

I was wondering if anyone knows how I could extend (physically and in dimension) the spatial extent of a small raster to match a bigger raster. I have used the "extend" function in terra but it's just returning the same size. I have tried the same thing in ArcGIS Pro with raster calculator but no luck. The part that I need to extend is the northernmost part of the small image. The extended part will be filled with zero.

The data are here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1c5AZS9onKUOzNoIVw3py3QFIRxITCjZ_?usp=sharing

Here are the raster info

```
>large 

class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 762, 762, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 3100, 3100  (x, y)
extent      : -3034878, -672677.7, 2022791, 4384991  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : Canada_Lambert_Conformal_Conic 
source      : Yukon_poly_raster_project.tif 
name        : Yukon_poly_raster_project 
min value   :                         0 
max value   :                       127
```

[image: Lager image: note the top part]

```
>small 

class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 426, 400, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 3096.673, 3098.812  (x, y)
extent      : -2284678, -1046008, 2551588, 3871682  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : Canada_Lambert_Conformal_Conic 
source      : FRT_Canada_yukon_ras_1.tif 
name        : FRT_Canada_yukon_ras_1 
min value   :                      3 
max value   :                     11
```

[image: Small raster: the northern most part is croped off compared to the large image]

Here's my R code:

```
library(terra)
r = extend(small, large)
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the northern 'haircut'' present in both your images, if I start with just your `small_raster.tif`, and use @robert-himans code below, all north values are present in extended large (and small). Thought it might be an artifact of the `png` process, but not, so something else slipped into your extent definition? Anyway, you should be set to go to your next process step, possibly starting in a new session...

Comment: Yea, the extent looks correct if we are going by the values. But the physical display is the issue and I just thought something must be missing as I need to be able to align the data using both the raster extents and the dataframes. I will see what happens in the next step.

Comment: Again, or specifically, I see a north trailing splay of white islands when plotting `small_raster.tif`, immediate after `rast(~/Downloads/small`, that isn't present in either of your images above, so something has crept in, hence my new session suggestion.

Comment: That's strange. I thought you were talking about the tiny northern protrusion in the large image. They all came from the same source except that the ones displayed here were copied from ArcGIS Pro display. But the display in R is not showing that trailing either. So, that could be an artefact.

Comment: They are tiny, and grey on white, hard to see except full screen, and the haircut may be an ArcGis artifact...Perhaps doing your analysis workflow/pipeline within one program to start (similar things come up using QGIS). Change all land values to something more nearly visible in small_raster.tif perhaps, to reassure.

Comment: You are right, the trail also showed in ArcGIS Pro for the small raster when I displayed it in a darker colour. But that shouldn't be a problem in this context because I'm only trying to extend the small image to match the extent of the large image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is not working with your R code? The results with extend look good to me.

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.7.38

large <- rast(nrow=762, ncol=762, ext=c(-3034878, -672677.7, 2022791, 4384991))
small <- rast(nrow=426, ncol=400, ext=c(-2284678, -1046008, 2551588, 3871682))

e <- extend(small, large)
e
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 763, 763, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 3096.675, 3098.812  (x, y)
#extent      : -3034073, -671310.3, 2021691, 4386085  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. :  

plot(ext(e), lwd=3)
lines(ext(small), col="red", lwd=2)
```

But I take it that what you are after is, in this case:

```
z <- resample(small, large)
```

Comment: If you compare the very northern ends of the images, you will notice the difference in the extent between the images. When I plotted the result from the code, it doesn't include the top northern portion that is in the larger image and that's what I want. The rasters need to be of equal extent to be used in the program that I'm working with.

Comment: Then perhaps you should rephrase your question (be more precise about what you want). I assume you need an equal extent and resolution. You can get there with `resample` (see expanded answer)

Comment: Cutting to the heart of the matter as ever.

Comment: When I `resampled` the data, they now appeared in the same extent and resolution but the image extent didn’t change either. Also, the `large` image wasn’t the raster that I needed to use for the `resampling`. And when I tried to `resample` with the exact data (see data file), all the data became `NA`, although this didn’t happen with `resampling` using the `small and large` rasters.

Comment: I'm trying to examine the coordinate system as the cause of NAs. I will give an update later

Comment: Thanks as usual, Robert.`Resampling` did the trick. I just needed to make sure that both rasters are in the same coordinate system.